# Send mail with default credentials in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, smtpclient

I want to send email in asp.net, found many useful links for it, and email is sending.
but in most of the examples we use

> client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

what if i want to send mail with

> client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

in this case, where will i set the host, port settings with credentials

Answer (score 1):

I think these settings are drawn from the [network node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164242.aspx) of the [system.net mailsettings configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx).  I've heard of people having issues with this, so YMMV.  But that could have just been mis-configuration, so it's worth a try.

Comment: How we utilize the SMTP settings in IIS.
any help ?

Comment: @user314230: I'm not sure what you're asking there.  Do you want IIS to use the SMTP settings configured in an application it hosts?  Or do you want an application it hosts to use its SMTP settings (if, say, IIS is also acting as an SMTP server here)?  Or something else?  It sounds like you might be trying to mix concerns that should stay separated.

Comment: I want my hosted application use the smtp settings from IIS.